# Why am I getting object error 91 when I use printform function in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Im having a problem where when I am openning up a userform and printing it out as well as printing out an excel sheet is gives me the error

> Object error 91

This is the code for the command button that starts loads the Userform and unloads the current userform

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Cells(10, 2).Value = stageBox.Value
    Cells(11, 2).Value = materialBox.Value
    Cells(12, 2).Value = POBox.Value
    Cells(13, 2).Value = MPIBox.Value
    Cells(14, 2).Value = LPIBox.Value
    Unload Me
    UserForm1.Show
    
End Sub
```

After it opens it it runs this

```
Dim Batch As String
Dim Draw As String
Dim Rev As String
Dim ScrapQR As String
Dim goodQty As String
Dim desc As String
Dim scrapQty As String
Dim stage As String
Dim material As String
Dim po As String
Dim mpi As String
Dim lpi As String


Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call gatherData
    Call popData
    Call printStuff
    Unload Me
End Sub

Sub gatherData()
    
    Batch = Cells(1, 2).Value
    Draw = Cells(3, 2).Value
    Rev = Cells(4, 2).Value
    ScrapQR = Cells(8, 2).Value
    goodQty = Cells(6, 2).Value
    scrapQty = Cells(7, 2).Value
    desc = Cells(2, 2).Value
    stage = Cells(10, 2).Value
    material = Cells(11, 2).Value
    po = Cells(12, 2).Value
    mpi = Cells(13, 2).Value
    lpi = Cells(14, 2).Value
      
End Sub

Sub popData()
    BatchBox.Text = Batch
    DrawBox.Text = Draw
    DescBox.Text = desc
    RevBox.Text = Rev
    GoodBox.Text = goodQty
    ScrapBox.Text = scrapQty
    DateBox = Date
    QRBox.Text = ScrapQR
    sBox.Text = Cells(10, 2).Value
    matBox.Text = Cells(11, 2).Value
    PBox.Text = Cells(12, 2).Value
    MBox.Text = Cells(13, 2).Value
    LBox.Text = Cells(14, 2).Value
    
    
End Sub

Sub printStuff()
    
    Dim fileName As String
    
    fileName = "Surface_Finish_" & Batch
    
    
    
    'Print Sheet1 exactly one page wide and tall
    With Worksheets("Surface Finish").PageSetup
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
    End With
    
    Worksheets("Surface Finish").ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        fileName:="N:\Buckets\Sdata\Dyllon_Dunton\" & fileName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        From:=1, _
        To:=1, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
        
    PrintForm
    
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try adding object `Me.PrintForm` or `UserForm1.PrintForm`

Answer (score -1):

You can not use unload command until you use .show, please remove this one.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Cells(10, 2).Value = stageBox.Value
    Cells(11, 2).Value = materialBox.Value
    Cells(12, 2).Value = POBox.Value
    Cells(13, 2).Value = MPIBox.Value
    Cells(14, 2).Value = LPIBox.Value
    Unload Me ' this one..................................
    UserForm1.Show
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What if the button is on a different form, not `Userform1` ?